# How to add your own loop to Qt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, xlib

I'm stuck on what to do. I have a while loop for xlib to read key presses when my Qt application isn't in focus. This is a copy paste from the ubuntu 16.04 python3-xlib package /usr/share/doc/python3-xlib/examples/record_demo.py. But this disrupts the functionality of the Qt application since it's only reading key presses and not handling Qt's event loops. Should I make my Qt application have a 2nd thread for this? Or can I hook xlib's loop onto Qt's loops?

I am working with python3, pyqt5, and python3-xlib.

Below is the file /usr/share/doc/python3-xlib/examples/record_demo.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#
# examples/record_demo.py -- demonstrate record extension
#
#    Copyright (C) 2006 Alex Badea <vamposdecampos@gmail.com>
#
#    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#    the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#    (at your option) any later version.
#
#    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#    GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#    along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
#    Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA

# Simple demo for the RECORD extension
# Not very much unlike the xmacrorec2 program in the xmacro package.

import sys
import os

# Change path so we find Xlib
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(sys.path[0], '..'))

from Xlib import X, XK, display
from Xlib.ext import record
from Xlib.protocol import rq

local_dpy = display.Display()
record_dpy = display.Display()

def lookup_keysym(keysym):
    for name in dir(XK):
        if name[:3] == "XK_" and getattr(XK, name) == keysym:
            return name[3:]
    return "[%d]" % keysym

def record_callback(reply):
    if reply.category != record.FromServer:
        return
    if reply.client_swapped:
        print("* received swapped protocol data, cowardly ignored")
        return
    if not len(reply.data) or reply.data[0] < 2:
        # not an event
        return

    data = reply.data
    while len(data):
        event, data = rq.EventField(None).parse_binary_value(data, record_dpy.display, None, None)

        if event.type in [X.KeyPress, X.KeyRelease]:
            pr = event.type == X.KeyPress and "Press" or "Release"

            keysym = local_dpy.keycode_to_keysym(event.detail, 0)
            if not keysym:
                print("KeyCode%s %s" % (pr, event.detail))
            else:
                print("KeyStr%s %s" % (pr, lookup_keysym(keysym)))

            if event.type == X.KeyPress and keysym == XK.XK_Escape:
                local_dpy.record_disable_context(ctx)
                local_dpy.flush()
                return
        elif event.type == X.ButtonPress:
            print("ButtonPress %s" % event.detail)
        elif event.type == X.ButtonRelease:
            print("ButtonRelease %s" % event.detail)
        elif event.type == X.MotionNotify:
            print("MotionNotify %i %i" % (event.root_x, event.root_y))


# Check if the extension is present
if not record_dpy.has_extension("RECORD"):
    print("RECORD extension not found")
    sys.exit(1)
r = record_dpy.record_get_version(0, 0)
print("RECORD extension version %d.%d" % (r.major_version, r.minor_version))

# Create a recording context; we only want key and mouse events
ctx = record_dpy.record_create_context(
        0,
        [record.AllClients],
        [{
                'core_requests': (0, 0),
                'core_replies': (0, 0),
                'ext_requests': (0, 0, 0, 0),
                'ext_replies': (0, 0, 0, 0),
                'delivered_events': (0, 0),
                'device_events': (X.KeyPress, X.MotionNotify),
                'errors': (0, 0),
                'client_started': False,
                'client_died': False,
        }])

# Enable the context; this only returns after a call to record_disable_context,
# while calling the callback function in the meantime
record_dpy.record_enable_context(ctx, record_callback)

# Finally free the context
record_dpy.record_free_context(ctx)
```

Comment: every GUI framework has some `Timer` class which lets you execute function periodically and then you can use it instead of `while True` or other loop.

Comment: I would say that everything you need is a `QThread` with reimplemented `run` method. Pack your while loop inside the `run` method and start the thread when you need it.

Comment: I'm not sure if that demo code has the library already automatically record all keypresses and uses the loop simply to print out the queue of them.

Comment: Apparently it's very bad to use a separate thread to run xlib code on a thread different from the main Qt GUI thread.

Answer (score 2):

Qt's event loop **is** an X event loop. You don't need another.

Since you're getting the information as callbacks from the event loop, this will "just work": as long as you use the same `xcb` library that Qt uses, and register the callback there, your callback will be invoked.

If you are getting the information as events, you can filter all native X events arriving to your application: use `QCoreApplication::installNativeEventFilter`. Your concrete implementation of `QAbstractNativeEventFilter` will receive native events as pointers to `xcb_generic_event_t`, see [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractnativeeventfilter.html#nativeEventFilter).

Interoperating with Python will be a bit complicated in case of events, though. You might need to implement the event filter in C++ and expose it to Python.

Comment: Doesn't this only work if the Qt application is in focus since no events are generated when the application isn't in focus? I am trying to read keys when the Qt application is not in focus.

Comment: The APIs you mention are supported in PyQt. But when the application *doesn't* have the focus (which is what the OP is interested in), it will only catch modifier key-presses. So I don't think it's going to be much help.

Comment: @user1766555. I think the simplest solution may be to use a separate thread and send signals back to the main thread.

Comment: @ekhumoro I'm thinking this too, it's starting to turn into a headache. I was unable to find any packages for python 3 that gave xcb support. I think I'll just use a second thread for the xlib loop for checking for the shortcut being pressed.

Comment: I gave up trying to make a keyboard shortcut reader. Python 3.5.2 is very unfriendly with XCB, and I ran into too many ruts.